# Can We Use Video Tag In Figure Tag In HTML5

Tags: html, video, figure

I am trying to build a clean HTML5 structure for my projects,
I didnt get the usage variety for Figure tag;
Can we really use Video in Figure as this page said:
http://oopeducation.com/html5/html5-figure-tag/

Or is it only for images?

Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes you can - according to the HTML5 spec, a `<figure>` permits [flow content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#flow-content) (which is comprised of both [flow elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow) & [normal character data](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data)).   Given that `<video>` & `<audio>` are both one of the many flow elements, it **is** perfectly valid for them to be nested within a figure.

[This](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) article from HTML5 Doctor seems to suggest the same thing, take a look.

Comment: Thank you, I read that page before for it, they write it like a foot note :)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible.

This is the definition of the `<figure>` tag as specified by W3C:

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document.
>
> The element can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams,
>   photos, code listings, etc, that are referred to from the main content
>   of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the
>   document, be moved away from that primary content, e.g. to the side of
>   the page, to dedicated pages, or to an appendix.

Here you can see an example extracted by W3C documentation, in which a `<video>` tag is included in a `<figure>` tag.

```
<figure>
 <video src="ex-b.mov"></video>
 <figcaption>Exhibit B. The <cite>Rough Copy</cite> trailer.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You can find the official W3C documentation here: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

Comment: while I was searching, there was no clean information about it, like a hidden reality :) Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. Also html5doctor.com is a trusted website so it's fine, anyway remember that the ONLY TRUE official documentation is that of W3C.org, they are the people who make the standard specifications. So if you can find info from multiple places, if you find info on w3c.org, choose that info. @Digerkam

Comment: You are right, I will keep it in mind! Most of time by searchs, W3C looks like a standart spec provider for browser programmer (with that site design and tons of informations) I know it is not, but that style :)

Comment: @Fabio Do you know if it is correct to use the fig caption tag to put the html5 video controls inside there, meaning putting button and slider tags?